# Using timezones with @nuxtjs/moment

Tags: vue.js, momentjs, nuxt.js, moment-timezone

We use the @nuxtjs/moment (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/moment) package in our nuxt application.

In our app we want to display GMT-timestamps in the users timezone like so:

```
<div>{{ $moment("2019-04-25 19:01:03").fromNow() }}</div>
```

But on my PC the result is just

`2 hours ago` because I'm based in germany.

Is there any way to set the default timezone to GMT so that the function works correctly? I've looked into moment-timezone but have no idea how to implement that to a nuxt application.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like there's an open issue in the repo for this [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/moment-module/issues/33).  What I'd suggest doing instead is adding moment-timezone as a [plugin](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins/) until that feature is merged.

Install

```
npm install moment-timezone
```

Add the plugin import

```
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  plugins: ['~/plugins/moment-timezone-inject.js']
}
```

Create the plugin

```
// ~/plugins/moment-timezone-inject.js

const moment = require('moment-timezone');
export default ({ app }, inject) => {
  // Inject into context, Due instances, and Vuex store
  inject('moment_timezone', moment)
}
```

Usage

```
// Add whatever timezone you need
<div>{{ $moment_timezone("2019-04-25 19:01:03").tz("Asia/Taipei"); }}</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

You can enable moment-timezone via the timezone option, by adding this to `nuxt.config.js`:

```
export default {
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/moment'
  ],
  moment: {
    timezone: true
  }
}
```

Setting default Time Zone:

```
moment: {
    defaultTimezone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
  }
```

More info:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxtjs/moment

Comment: Even enable I can't use moment.tz.guess, why ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which country the date you put in the $moment function is for, you should set the same in this section

Comment: My backend gives the UTC date, so I set the same

Comment: moment: {
    defaultTimezone: 'UTC'
  },